# Scheduled workflow is not executed

Tags: circleci

This is my circleci 2.0 config file

```
docker: &docker
  - image: circleci/python:2.7-stretch-node

version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker: *docker
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: bash job.sh

workflows:
  version: 2
  hourly:
    triggers:
      - schedule:
          cron: "15 0-23/1 * * *"
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - master
    jobs:
      - build
```

I have used `cricleci config validate` to confirm that there is no syntax, however there is no update on the circleci frontend at all.

By 'no update' I mean I am expecting to see another job executed after the last commit of the branch `5006/enable-circle2`, which was branched off `master`.

[image]

Subsequently I have add minor change to the yml file and push the commits. Yet nothing show up.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it turns out that

1. Although circleci 2  documentation claims that [it supports 'crontab' syntax for job scheduling](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/),

[image]

It does not support '/number' syntax. i.e. circleci 2 does not understand  `0-23/1`

2. To find out what's gone wrong, you have to go and check the `workflow` page

[image]

You can get there by using url `https://circleci.com/gh/<project>/workflows/<repo>`.

Comment: > Although circleci 2 documentation claims that
It says right there in that section that it does not support fraction notation. Just plain integers.